# Getting variable from XML, parsing it and then forming a SQL query

Tags: sql, xml, powershell

I have one `config.xml` file for configuration and another (`steps.xml`) that acts as a guide and contains steps that generate scripts for execution.

`config.xml`:

```
<CFG>
    <Server>sql-server.com</Server>
    <Database>mySQLDB</Database>
</CFG>
```

`steps.xml`:

```
<Steps>
    <Step no="1">
        <script>
          USE [<v>$configs.CFG.Database</v>]
          UPDATE server_name SET name = '<v>$configs.CFG.Server</v>'
        </script>
    </Step>
</Steps>
```

I use `<v></v>` to tell my script where the variables are. I don't know if that is a good way to go about.

Then I run this script to parse the files:

```
$configFile = 'd:\ps\config.xml'
$stepsfile = 'd:\ps\steps.xml'
[xml]$steps = Get-Content -Path $stepsfile 
[xml]$configs = Get-Content -Path $configFile

$t = $Steps.Steps.Step[0].script.v

foreach ($var in $t){
    $exec = Invoke-Expression $var
    # use $exec to form a working script
}
```

I can resolve the actual information from configuration file but I am stuck at putting it back together. I know I can use this to get full script text:

```
$Steps.Steps.Step[0].script."#text"
```

But I am lost how can I pinpoint the location of variables to put resolved names back into it and form a usable script.

The output I'm trying to achieve should be:

```sql
USE [mySQLDB]
UPDATE server_name SET name = 'sql-server.com'
```

Comment: Are the configuration files your own design and you can change, or is that something you have to live with? My first impression, they are really tedious to parse and potentially insecure.

Comment: I can change the design of configurations as i go, any suggestions that would make this easier and safer to implement are more than welcome :)

Comment: `Invoke-Expression` leads to arbitrary code execution. When the data that you are parsing is going to be SQL, `Invoke-Sql` is, let's say, only a threat to your database instead the whole system. A good topic to study would be: parametrized sql queries.

Comment: I am just generating the queries, I will not execute them from this script.

Comment: Here's a malicious example: `<Steps><Step no=1><script>Restart-Computer</script></Step></Steps>`. To avoid that from happening, you should do string manipulation without evaluating it as code.

Comment: @ConfusB Had you actually tested your code with the XML sample you provided (like you're supposed to when creating a [mcve]) you would have noticed that neither `$xml.Steps.Step[0].script.v` nor `$xml.Steps.Step[0].script.'#text'` work unless there are at least 2 `<Step>` nodes in the XML file.

Answer (score 1):

[`Invoke-Expression` is considered harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/). Do not use it.

Instead of using nested XML nodes in the script body you could use any kind of placeholder that normally wouldn't appear in the SQL code (e.g. the names of the nodes from `$configs` in curly brackets: `{Server}` and `{Database}`) and then insert the values via string replacements.

```
foreach ($step in $steps.SelectNodes('//script')) {
    foreach ($cfg in $configs.SelectNodes('/CFG/*')) {
        $step.'#text' = $step.'#text'.Replace("{$($cfg.Name)}", $cfg.'#text')
    }
}
```